# Mysql select query to match zipcodes

Tags: mysql

Table Name : contacts

```
id | postal_code
1  | 41575-8907
2  | 41575
3  | 65789
4  | 396001
5  | 65789-0013
```

What i want is check postal_code and if its of pattern `xxxxx-xxxx` then only take first 5 digits and discarding `-XXXX`.

May be checking against regular expression like this : "`[0-9]{5}-[0-9{4}]`".

I want a select mysql query that shows below output.

```
id | postal_code
1  | 41575
2  | 41575
3  | 65789
4  | 396001
5  | 65789
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) like this:

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(code_postal,'-',1); 
FROM contacts
```

**DEMO**:

```
mysql> select * from contacts;
+----+-------------+
| id | code_postal |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 12345-456   |
|  2 | 12346       |
|  3 | 12347       |
|  4 | 12348-7865  |
|  5 | 10348-77765 |
+----+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, substring_index(code_postal,'-',1) from contacts;
+----+------------------------------------+
| id | substring_index(code_postal,'-',1) |
+----+------------------------------------+
|  1 | 12345                              |
|  2 | 12346                              |
|  3 | 12347                              |
|  4 | 12348                              |
|  5 | 10348                              |
+----+------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```